# What is C++/C used for in a web environment?

Tags: php, c++, c

I may be interpreting this incorrectly, but I stumbled upon [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_languages_used_in_most_popular_websites) of programming languages used on popular sites.

I noticed that C and C++ are frequently used on sites like youtube, google, twitter and facebook. I always assumed that c/c++ were used for non-web based environments such as desktop applications and embedded systems programming.

My programming experience is pretty much web based languages only, aside from a bit of Python for some small projects. What kinds of tasks are these sites doing that they need to use c++/c and how do they interact with a more typical web languages like PHP? Would c++ be used similarly to PHP for example (handling requests and such), or would it be more like optimizing server settings and networking?

Comment: All these languages are capable to do the same, just differently, why would it be so strange to use them to serve web content?

Comment: I imagine it'll be for the backend on websites such as Facebook/Twitter/Google... I cannot see any benefit in using it to create front-end content though.

Comment: Youtube, google, twitter, etc have "backend" code written in C or C++.

Comment: If you use Python or PHP or Apache or Nginx or MySQL or... you are indirectly using C

Comment: This question is not really a good fit for SO, it might be better on [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: C/C++ for performance.  Nothing can really beat it.  The facebook game War Commander was totally rewritten in C++ because of performance limitations.

Comment: @KScottPiel: Since when can php be executed in the browser? Can you show me a single example site that uses it?

Comment: @KScottPiel: PHP is definitely used extensively for serverside work. I have my own small site, as well as working with the owner of www.aquaticrepublicnetwork.com to develop it's "daughter sites". Almost all done in PHP on the server. JavaScript tends to be used on "client side" work.

Comment: @KScottPiel _PHP ... is exetubale in the browser_ is a completely wrong statement.  PHP is executed on the server side and results are sent to the browser.  The browser has no idea that the information it receives has been generated by PHP - and frankly couldn't care less.

Comment: My apologies... it was indeed a very wrong statement... I was intending to differentiate between running in the web server application and the local O/S and somewhere along the way shifted into thinking in the Java Applet mindset versus server-side. I've deleted the prior response... though the general concept I was after remains... C/C++ is no better/worse a web solution, the issue is about how it is deployed. (though I would argue C/C++ native apps can be more efficient in many cases)

Comment: C/C++ is only unpopular for web development because no hosting company in their right mind will let you run a compiled executable on a shared server. </discussion>